# Interact with Skype Desktop using API

Tags: c#, skype, skypedeveloper

Spent last few days researching ways to interact with the latest install of Skype Desktop. Hitting roadblocks on every option.

Tried the following -

- Skype4COM lib - Does not work with the latest build of Skype. I tried downloading Skype build version < 8, but was unable to attach the Skype.exe process as part of using Skype4COMLib
- Skype integration with Outlook 2013 and have a VSTO Plugin for outlook interact with Skype - The VSTO plugins fails to interact with Skype panel
- Skype to Slack interaction using Sameroom.io - My contacts in Skype are not on Slack.
- Skype to Skype for Business - My contacts in Skype are not on Skype network, and would not be able to register with Skype for business.
- Skype to Pidgin - [This works]
- Skype Web SDK - After trials the requirement is to run a Lync Server. Skype Web SDK does not work with Skype personal.
- Skype Bots - Still working and trying to understand this. Have created an azure bot, and included in my Skype account, but how do I make the bot impersonate me and respond to all the messages posted by my Skype contacts. Because, my Skype contacts will be chatting with me and not with my bot.

I would like to interact with the Skype users in my contacts when they send messages to my account. The goal is the parse message sent to my Skype account, process message, and send the output back to the user who originated the message.

I would really appreciate if the community can help me with giving pointers on how to achieve the above.

Thanks

Comment: `Tried the following -` Please tell us more specifically about what you tried and what did and didn't work.

Comment: Updated my posting

Comment: "Skype to Pidgin - Pidgin does not interact with Skype Personal" It definitely does https://github.com/EionRobb/skype4pidgin/tree/master/skypeweb

Comment: Skype To Pidgin - Does work. Thanks Robb. I did try using a different account, and wala...I can see my skype messages in pidgin. Great plugin Robb